# without template, need to render not return json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm trying to make code from a Sinatra app work in the Rails context. The Sinatra app uses  ajax requests to trigger the Sinatra routes/controller actions. For example, if you trigger the new function on a javascript model

```
   new: function() {
      var _this = this;

      $.ajax({
        url: "/gamestart",
        type: "POST",  
     ....
```

It will trigger the route/controller code in the Sinatra app

```
   post "/new" do

   end
```

When I tried to make this work in Rails, I'm getting a 500 internal server error. In my Rails app, the new_game button triggers an ajax request to a Rails route which triggers a controller action, and that controller action uses the Rails model to get data from the database. For some reason that doesn't seem like the right way to do it in Rails, and I'm wondering if it's the reason I'm getting the server error

```
   GET http://localhost:3000/gamestart 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

If possible, can you tell me where in the chain of actions outlined below that error is arising and what I might do to fix it.

**1** Click on the new game button triggers 'startNewGame' method

```
'click #new_game': 'startNewGame',
```

**2** The startNewGame method calls method on Game model

```
 startNewGame: function() {
          this.model.new();
        },
```

**3** The new method in the Game model makes a GET request to the url '/gamestart'. I also tried a post request. I don't know why it would need to be a post request, but neither worked. (In the original Sinatra application, the gamestart url led immediately into the function  post '/gamestart' do...)

```
 new: function() {
      var _this = this;
  $.ajax({
    url: "/gamestart",
    type: "GET",              \\\ also tried POST
    success: function(response) {
      var json = $.parseJSON(response);

      _this.set({lost: false});
      _this.set({win: false});
      _this.trigger("gameStartedEvent", json);
    }
  })
},
```

**4** I directed the url to a controller action in Rails router file

```
match 'gamestart' => 'locations#gamestart', :via => :get
```

Note, in the original Sinatra application, the route and the controller action were combined

**5** The gamestart method of the locations_controller.rb

```
    def gamestart 
       word = Word.get_random
       masquerade_word = Word.masquerade(word)
       session[:word] = word
       session[:incorrect_guesses] = 0
       session[:chars_left] = word.size
       session[:revealed_word] = masquerade_word
       {:word => masquerade_word}.to_json
    end
```

**6** The get_random method on the word model Word.rb, which is called from locations controller

```
   def get_random
      words = []
      locations = Location.all (this pulls up the names of the locations from the db)
      locations.each do |e|
        words << e.name
      end 
      words.sample
    end
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
GET http://localhost:3000/gamestart 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:8215
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/gamestart". jquery.js:8215
send jquery.js:8215
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7767
window.Game.Backbone.Model.extend game.js:27
window.OptionsView.Backbone.View.extend.startNewGame optionsView.js:14
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3062
elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

Note, in the original Sinatra application, the route and the controller action were combined in the usual Sinatra way

```
 post "/gamestart" do
   word = Word.get_random
   masquerade_word = Word.masquerade(word)
   session[:word] = word
   session[:incorrect_guesses] = 0
   session[:chars_left] = word.size
   session[:revealed_word] = masquerade_word
   {:word => masquerade_word}.to_json
end
```

**UPDATE**
The 500 error seemed to be triggered by a missing template. This method in locations controller wasn't rendering anything. It didn't have a view file. I therefore changed the controller to make it respond_to :json and then use respond_with at the end of the action, but that triggered a 406 error.

```
   def gamestart 
       word = Word.get_random
       masquerade_word = Word.masquerade(word)
       session[:word] = word
       session[:incorrect_guesses] = 0
       session[:chars_left] = word.size
       session[:revealed_word] = masquerade_word
       {:word => masquerade_word}.to_json
    end
```

**became**  now triggers 406 error

```
    respond_to :json

    def gamestart 
       word = Word.get_random
       masquerade_word = Word.masquerade(word)
       session[:word] = word
       session[:incorrect_guesses] = 0
       session[:chars_left] = word.size
       session[:revealed_word] = masquerade_word
       plainvariable = {:word => masquerade_word}.to_json    ###changed
       respond_with plainvariable                          ###changed
    end
```

Comment: I'm sorry, for some reason I can't get some of the code to format even when I click the code braces

Comment: What do you get when you load http://localhost:3000/gamestart in your web browser?

Comment: Is there anything in the server's error log to go with that 500?

Comment: @akshat  It says missing template error: template is missing.  That controller action doesn't have a view file--the json response is supposed to return to the new action of the model, which triggers another backdone function.  Do you know how I would rewrite that gamestart method (see number 5 in OP) to eliminate that error?

Comment: @muistooshort there's a missing template error. see my comment directly preceding this one. I'm not sure how to modify the gamestart method to fix that. There's two other controller methods that will probably trigger the same problem, as they just return data to the backbone model that made the ajax request, however, I haven't been able to check those two other methods because this first one is creating a problem. Since the application uses the json gem, and the methods end with to_json, I didn't think I could do respond_to :json respond_with etc in the controller, as that'd be redundant

Comment: @akshat please see the update in the OP

Comment: @muistooshort please see the update in the op

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say that your `gamestart` controller method is causing a server error due to a missing template. If we look at that controller method:

```
def gamestart 
  #...
  {:word => masquerade_word}.to_json
end
```

we see that it *returns* a JSON string but it neglects to *render* anything. You don't call any rendering or redirection methods so Rails helpfully (ha ha) assumes that you want to render the `gamestart` view template; but, you have no such thing so you get an error.

You should render your JSON, not return it; something more like this:

```
def gamestart
  #...
  render :json => { :word => masquerade_word }
end
```

Comment: very thank you sir. does it otherwise seem normal that I'm using ajax to trigger the controller action through a router?

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil: No worries, I find that all the magical helpfulness in Rails often gets in the way and makes tracking down problems a lot harder than it should be.